# How to prevent compiler from optimizing out calls to Trace.Write() and Debug.Write() in mstest

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

It worked previously within this same project, but doesn't work now.  I haven't had any luck with the solutions presented in any related question I could find on this site or elsewhere.

I have written a program to perform some long-running processes, and I have put the code into a solution containing only an mstest project, preferring to avoid any sort of U/I necessity whatsoever.  I would like to have some status emitted into the Output window, using code similar to the following:

```
if (counter % 100 == 0)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Inserted {0} records into {1}.", counter, proprietaryDetails));
}
```

I am running the tests using the IDE, not the command line.  Nothing appears in the Output Window.  I cannot set breakpoints on Debug.Write() or Trace.Write() statements when I am debugging.

I have done the following:

1. Ensured I'm building the project in Debug mode.
2. Ensured that "Program Output" is checked when I right click the output window
3. Tried both debugging and running the tests using Ctrl-R + T and Ctrl-R + Ctrl-T.
4. I have no .config file which might be disabling the default trace listener.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Tou haven't provided enough information for us to tell what's really wrong. How is `counter` being changed?  If it's in another thread, the compiler might think it's not really changing and optimize the block away.

Comment: Project + Properties, Build tab, ensure that the "Define Xxx constant" options are checked.

Comment: Peter Ritchie, that's really good thinking, but not the case.  I should have put a simpler example in my question, such as "Trace.WriteLine("hi");" as the first line of code gets skipped."

Comment: And Hans, your suggestion fixed the problem.  At long last!  I had selected ever debug option under the sun everywhere but this.  I'll gladly mark your answer as the correct one if you're interested in inputting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like the following would help?

```
TextWriterTraceListener myWriter = newTextWriterTraceListener(System.Console.Out);
Debug.Listeners.Add(myWriter);
Trace.Listeners.Add(myWriter);
```

Comment: This isn't doing the trick, but thanks.  These three lines get executed according to my break point, but a call immediately after to Trace.WriteLine("hi"); gets skipped just as before, as though the compiler is actually optimizing that line of code out.

Comment: ... and when I hover over Trace.Listeners I can see that it contains a DefaultTraceListener and a TextWriterTraceListener.